# How to run Steam Worms in DOSBox?

Tags: steam

I've installed Steam with Wine on my Mac. Then I installed Worms. It comes with an integrated DOSBox for Windows. For Windows only, unfortunately; although DOSBox is available for Linux and Mac as well. It works via the Steam client in Wine, but it's kind of a hassle to start Steam in Wine to run Worms in a DOSBox.

So I installed DOSBox for Mac via brew to run Worms directly. In

```
.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steamapps/common/Worms
```

and its sub-directories there are quite a few .BAT and .EXE files. I think I've tried them all

```
dosbox <file>
```

but no success so far in launching Worms. I think I read somewhere that Worms is DRM free. In theory this should work I think. So, how to run Worms in DOSBox?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to Stephen's answer, I found the file `worms.conf`. Using that running

```
dosbox -conf worms.conf
```

had the only effect of starting DOSBox in fullscreen mode. Then I've investigated the file a little and found this line:

```
[autoexec]
imgmount d .\worms.CUE -t iso -fs iso
```

which I changed to

```
[autoexec]
imgmount d ./worms.cue -t iso -fs iso
```

This had no effect however. What now?

This is the full content of `worms.conf`:

```
# This is the configurationfile for DOSBox 0.74. (Please use the latest version of DOSBox)# Lines starting with a # are commentlines and are ignored by DOSBox.
# They are used to (briefly) document the effect of each option.

[sdl]
#       fullscreen: Start dosbox directly in fullscreen. (Press ALT-Enter to go back)
#       fulldouble: Use double buffering in fullscreen. It can reduce screen flickering, but it can also result in a slow DOSBox.
#   fullresolution: What resolution to use for fullscreen: original or fixed size (e.g. 1024x768).
#                     Using your monitor's native resolution with aspect=true might give the best results.
#                     If you end up with small window on a large screen, try an output different from surface.
# windowresolution: Scale the window to this size IF the output device supports hardware scaling.
#                     (output=surface does not!)
#           output: What video system to use for output.
#                   Possible values: surface, overlay, opengl, openglnb, ddraw.
#         autolock: Mouse will automatically lock, if you click on the screen. (Press CTRL-F10 to unlock)
#      sensitivity: Mouse sensitivity.
#      waitonerror: Wait before closing the console if dosbox has an error.
#         priority: Priority levels for dosbox. Second entry behind the comma is for when dosbox is not focused/minimized.
#                     pause is only valid for the second entry.
#                   Possible values: lowest, lower, normal, higher, highest, pause.
#       mapperfile: File used to load/save the key/event mappings from. Resetmapper only works with the defaul value.
#     usescancodes: Avoid usage of symkeys, might not work on all operating systems.

fullscreen=true
fulldouble=true
fullresolution=original
windowresolution=original
output=surface
autolock=true
sensitivity=80
waitonerror=true
priority=higher,normal
mapperfile=mapper-0.74.map
usescancodes=true

[dosbox]
# language: Select another language file.
#  machine: The type of machine tries to emulate.
#           Possible values: hercules, cga, tandy, pcjr, ega, vgaonly, svga_s3, svga_et3000, svga_et4000, svga_paradise, vesa_nolfb, vesa_oldvbe.
# captures: Directory where things like wave, midi, screenshot get captured.
#  memsize: Amount of memory DOSBox has in megabytes.
#             This value is best left at its default to avoid problems with some games,
#             though few games might require a higher value.
#             There is generally no speed advantage when raising this value.

language=
machine=svga_s3
captures=capture
memsize=16

[render]
# frameskip: How many frames DOSBox skips before drawing one.
#    aspect: Do aspect correction, if your output method doesn't support scaling this can slow things down!.
#    scaler: Scaler used to enlarge/enhance low resolution modes.
#              If 'forced' is appended, then the scaler will be used even if the result might not be desired.
#            Possible values: none, normal2x, normal3x, advmame2x, advmame3x, advinterp2x, advinterp3x, hq2x, hq3x, 2xsai, super2xsai, supereagle, tv2x, tv3x, rgb2x, rgb3x, scan2x, scan3x.

frameskip=0
aspect=false
scaler=normal2x

[cpu]
#      core: CPU Core used in emulation. auto will switch to dynamic if available and appropriate.
#            Possible values: auto, dynamic, normal, simple.
#   cputype: CPU Type used in emulation. auto is the fastest choice.
#            Possible values: auto, 386, 386_slow, 486_slow, pentium_slow, 386_prefetch.
#    cycles: Amount of instructions DOSBox tries to emulate each millisecond.
#            Setting this value too high results in sound dropouts and lags.
#            Cycles can be set in 3 ways:
#              'auto'          tries to guess what a game needs.
#                              It usually works, but can fail for certain games.
#              'fixed #number' will set a fixed amount of cycles. This is what you usually need if 'auto' fails.
#                              (Example: fixed 4000).
#              'max'           will allocate as much cycles as your computer is able to handle.
#
#            Possible values: auto, fixed, max.
#   cycleup: Amount of cycles to decrease/increase with keycombo.(CTRL-F11/CTRL-F12)
# cycledown: Setting it lower than 100 will be a percentage.

core=auto
cputype=auto
cycles=auto
cycleup=10
cycledown=20

[mixer]
#   nosound: Enable silent mode, sound is still emulated though.
#      rate: Mixer sample rate, setting any device's rate higher than this will probably lower their sound quality.
#            Possible values: 44100, 48000, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000, 49716.
# blocksize: Mixer block size, larger blocks might help sound stuttering but sound will also be more lagged.
#            Possible values: 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 512, 256.
# prebuffer: How many milliseconds of data to keep on top of the blocksize.

nosound=false
rate=44100
blocksize=1024
prebuffer=20

[midi]
#     mpu401: Type of MPU-401 to emulate.
#             Possible values: intelligent, uart, none.
# mididevice: Device that will receive the MIDI data from MPU-401.
#             Possible values: default, win32, alsa, oss, coreaudio, coremidi, none.
# midiconfig: Special configuration options for the device driver. This is usually the id of the device you want to use.
#               See the README/Manual for more details.

mpu401=intelligent
mididevice=default
midiconfig=

[sblaster]
#  sbtype: Type of Soundblaster to emulate. gb is Gameblaster.
#          Possible values: sb1, sb2, sbpro1, sbpro2, sb16, gb, none.
#  sbbase: The IO address of the soundblaster.
#          Possible values: 220, 240, 260, 280, 2a0, 2c0, 2e0, 300.
#     irq: The IRQ number of the soundblaster.
#          Possible values: 7, 5, 3, 9, 10, 11, 12.
#     dma: The DMA number of the soundblaster.
#          Possible values: 1, 5, 0, 3, 6, 7.
#    hdma: The High DMA number of the soundblaster.
#          Possible values: 1, 5, 0, 3, 6, 7.
# sbmixer: Allow the soundblaster mixer to modify the DOSBox mixer.
# oplmode: Type of OPL emulation. On 'auto' the mode is determined by sblaster type. All OPL modes are Adlib-compatible, except for 'cms'.
#          Possible values: auto, cms, opl2, dualopl2, opl3, none.
#  oplemu: Provider for the OPL emulation. compat might provide better quality (see oplrate as well).
#          Possible values: default, compat, fast.
# oplrate: Sample rate of OPL music emulation. Use 49716 for highest quality (set the mixer rate accordingly).
#          Possible values: 44100, 49716, 48000, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000.

sbtype=sb16
sbbase=220
irq=7
dma=1
hdma=5
sbmixer=true
oplmode=auto
oplemu=default
oplrate=44100

[gus]
#      gus: Enable the Gravis Ultrasound emulation.
#  gusrate: Sample rate of Ultrasound emulation.
#           Possible values: 44100, 48000, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000, 49716.
#  gusbase: The IO base address of the Gravis Ultrasound.
#           Possible values: 240, 220, 260, 280, 2a0, 2c0, 2e0, 300.
#   gusirq: The IRQ number of the Gravis Ultrasound.
#           Possible values: 5, 3, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12.
#   gusdma: The DMA channel of the Gravis Ultrasound.
#           Possible values: 3, 0, 1, 5, 6, 7.
# ultradir: Path to Ultrasound directory. In this directory
#           there should be a MIDI directory that contains
#           the patch files for GUS playback. Patch sets used
#           with Timidity should work fine.

gus=false
gusrate=44100
gusbase=240
gusirq=5
gusdma=3
ultradir=C:\ULTRASND

[speaker]
# pcspeaker: Enable PC-Speaker emulation.
#    pcrate: Sample rate of the PC-Speaker sound generation.
#            Possible values: 44100, 48000, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000, 49716.
#     tandy: Enable Tandy Sound System emulation. For 'auto', emulation is present only if machine is set to 'tandy'.
#            Possible values: auto, on, off.
# tandyrate: Sample rate of the Tandy 3-Voice generation.
#            Possible values: 44100, 48000, 32000, 22050, 16000, 11025, 8000, 49716.
#    disney: Enable Disney Sound Source emulation. (Covox Voice Master and Speech Thing compatible).

pcspeaker=true
pcrate=44100
tandy=auto
tandyrate=44100
disney=true

[joystick]
# joysticktype: Type of joystick to emulate: auto (default), none,
#               2axis (supports two joysticks),
#               4axis (supports one joystick, first joystick used),
#               4axis_2 (supports one joystick, second joystick used),
#               fcs (Thrustmaster), ch (CH Flightstick).
#               none disables joystick emulation.
#               auto chooses emulation depending on real joystick(s).
#               (Remember to reset dosbox's mapperfile if you saved it earlier)
#               Possible values: auto, 2axis, 4axis, 4axis_2, fcs, ch, none.
#        timed: enable timed intervals for axis. Experiment with this option, if your joystick drifts (away).
#     autofire: continuously fires as long as you keep the button pressed.
#       swap34: swap the 3rd and the 4th axis. can be useful for certain joysticks.
#   buttonwrap: enable button wrapping at the number of emulated buttons.

joysticktype=auto
timed=true
autofire=false
swap34=false
buttonwrap=false

[serial]
# serial1: set type of device connected to com port.
#          Can be disabled, dummy, modem, nullmodem, directserial.
#          Additional parameters must be in the same line in the form of
#          parameter:value. Parameter for all types is irq (optional).
#          for directserial: realport (required), rxdelay (optional).
#                           (realport:COM1 realport:ttyS0).
#          for modem: listenport (optional).
#          for nullmodem: server, rxdelay, txdelay, telnet, usedtr,
#                         transparent, port, inhsocket (all optional).
#          Example: serial1=modem listenport:5000
#          Possible values: dummy, disabled, modem, nullmodem, directserial.
# serial2: see serial1
#          Possible values: dummy, disabled, modem, nullmodem, directserial.
# serial3: see serial1
#          Possible values: dummy, disabled, modem, nullmodem, directserial.
# serial4: see serial1
#          Possible values: dummy, disabled, modem, nullmodem, directserial.

serial1=dummy
serial2=dummy
serial3=disabled
serial4=disabled

[dos]
#            xms: Enable XMS support.
#            ems: Enable EMS support.
#            umb: Enable UMB support.
# keyboardlayout: Language code of the keyboard layout (or none).

xms=true
ems=true
umb=true
keyboardlayout=auto

[ipx]
# ipx: Enable ipx over UDP/IP emulation.

ipx=false

[autoexec]
# Lines in this section will be run at startup.
# You can put your MOUNT lines here.
imgmount d .\worms.CUE -t iso -fs iso
```

And this is the content of the Worms directory:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    2960937 Feb 17 20:30 02.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4648429 Feb 17 20:30 03.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4451976 Feb 17 20:31 04.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4331940 Feb 17 20:32 05.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4254838 Feb 17 20:32 06.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4170134 Feb 17 20:31 07.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4079885 Feb 17 20:34 08.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4156349 Feb 17 20:35 09.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4358277 Feb 17 20:33 10.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4433647 Feb 17 20:33 11.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    5359742 Feb 17 20:35 12.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    4530887 Feb 17 20:36 13.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20     822162 Feb 17 20:32 14.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20     268685 Feb 17 20:30 15.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20     294289 Feb 17 20:30 16.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20     207515 Feb 17 20:30 17.ogg
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20    6153385 Feb 17 20:36 18.ogg
drwxr-xr-x  14 501  20        448 Jun  4 12:41 DOSBox
drwxr-xr-x   4 501  20        128 Feb 17 20:39 DriveC
drwxr-xr-x  13 501  20        416 Feb 17 20:39 WormsCD
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20         81 Feb 17 20:31 runworms.bat
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20          7 Jun  4 12:39 steam_appid.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20  134903664 Feb 17 20:39 worms.bin
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20      10993 Jun  4 12:01 worms.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 501  20       1092 Feb 17 20:37 worms.cue
```

This is the content of `runworms.bat`:

```
.\dosbox\dosbox .\drivec\goworms.bat -conf .\worms.conf -fullscreen -exit
exit
```

and DriveC/goworms.bat:

```
cd worms
call worms.bat
```

and now DriveC/WORMS/WORMS.BAT:

```
@cls
@C:\Worms\bin\black.exe
SET dos4g=quiet
SET wormscfg=C:\Worms\worms.cfg
SET wormscd=D:
@C:\Worms\bin\wrms
```

there is another file that might be of interest:
DriveC/WORMS/ORIG_WORMS.BAT:

```
@cls
@echo PREPARING TO PLAY WORMS     Copyright 1995/96 Team17 Software Ltd.
@echo.
@choice /C:NS /N /T:N,3 "Press S to skip intro and quick-load the game..."
@if errorlevel 2 goto skip
@if errorlevel 1 goto intro

:intro
@cls
@C:\Worms\bin\black.exe
SET dos4g=quiet
SET wormscfg=C:\Worms\worms.cfg
SET wormscd=D:
@D:\fmv\play D:\fmv\logo2.avi
@D:\fmv\play D:\fmv\logo1.avi
@D:\fmv\play D:\fmv\cinadd.avi
@D:\fmv\play D:\fmv\armup.avi
@C:\Worms\bin\black.exe
@C:\Worms\bin\wrms
@goto end
:skip
@cls
@C:\Worms\bin\black.exe
SET dos4g=quiet
SET wormscfg=C:\Worms\worms.cfg
SET wormscd=D:
@C:\Worms\bin\wrms
:end
```

And this is the content of the DriveC/WORMS/BIN/ directory:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501  20   20604 Feb 17 20:33 BLACK.EXE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501  20   15824 Feb 17 20:36 MODESET.EXE
-rwxr-xr-x  1 501  20  493309 Feb 17 20:35 WRMS.EXE
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Steam support issue, not a Unix and Linux issue

Comment: This is NOT a Steam support issue, as I'm trying to do something NOT intended by Steam or the developer of the game.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are using DOSbox correctly. I don't think this is a Unix and Linux issue.

Comment: Where would you recommend me asking this question, if not here?

Comment: [Worms in DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com/comp_list.php?showID=656&letter=W)

Comment: @Alexander why would that make it off topic here? We cover any attempt to run a program on a *nix machine, so why would steam be any different?

Comment: @terdon, I just think this is specifically about Steam. DOSBox, lauching DOS applications and a proprietary game, not Unix and Linux in general.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach to run a Steam (or GOG, or ...) game which uses DOSBox, without using the provided DOSBox, is to find the configuration file that’s used, and start DOSBox with that:

```
cd ..../common/Worms
dosbox -conf fullscreen.conf
```

(replacing `fullscreen.conf` as appropriate).

This will ensure that everything is set up correctly — CD images and directories mounted, graphics options set, etc.

In this particular case, `runworms.bat` gives the complete recipe; adapted for Linux or macOS:

```
dosbox DriveC/goworms.bat -conf worms.conf -fullscreen -exit
```